# Баг с выводом личных данных

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

Создано вэб приложение на node js.

- Суть приложения: Аутентификация через стим и вывод личной информации 
  из бд mysql.
- Описание бага: При заходе первого человека в аккаунт ему отображаются
  его личные данные, но если в свой аккаунт заходит кто-то    другой,
  то всем показывается информация последнего кто зашел в свой    акк.
  Из догадок решения только создание каждому юзеру уникального id.
  Но с точки зрения безопасности - это проблема. Да и запросы в бд идут
  не только SELECT, но и UPDATE.

Собственно сам код: [Код](https://hastebin.com/ameyezunah.js)

Буду рад помощи, так как не особо силен в node js. Но платформы лучше не нашел.

Upd: Может ли быть проблема в этом?

```
app.use(session({
   secret: 'your secret',
   name: 'name of session id',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Upd2: Скорее всего проблема заключена в глобальной переменной `playerData = []`
из которой происходит вывод в ejs файлы. Если кто-то поможет с выводом - буду рад.

Comment: Покажите вашу бд полностью, покажите как вы авторизуетесь. Почему вы говорите про ID юзера и то, что это проблема с безопасностью. Опишите как вы делаете авторизацию и на что опираетесь

Comment: @MoloF [код аpp.js](https://pastebin.com/ZvXM5gJa) Я знаю о проблемах дублирования запроса в pp. Я пытаюсь решить данную проблему.

Comment: Весь необходимый код нужно прикладывать прямо к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле проблема заключалась не в глобальной переменной `steamID`, а в глобальной переменной вывода `playerData`. 
Проблема была решена так:

```js
 res.render('account', {
                user: req.user,
                playerCharName: playerData.charName,
                playercharNickname: playerData.charNickname,
                playercharSurname: playerData.charSurname,
                playerGold: playerData.gold
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Скорее всего проблема в этой глобальной переменной

```js
steamID = profile.id;
checkPlayerExist(steamID);
```

2. У вас в коде повсюду потенциальные SQL инъекции.

```js
'SELECT name FROM armadb.players WHERE playerid = """' + playerId + '"""'
```

Comment: Какова ваша рекомендация глядя на код? Как мне брать steamID из скоупа с аутентификацией? Как мне избежать глобализации данных и выдавать каждому юзеру его значение из бд?

Comment: Я паспорт не юзал, но, кажется, тот объект, что вы передаёте в `done(null, profile);` доступен через `req.user`, т.е. для каждого юзера запрашивается ID и сохраняется в куку.

Comment: Может подскажете метод использования? Был бы рад примеру.

Comment: К сожалению нет. Я заменил `getUserData(steamID);` на `getUserData(req.user.id);` все равно всем юзерам транслируется информация о последнем пользователе, а не о них самих.

Comment: Вот тут в примерах нет никаких глобальных переменных и всё работает. https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam/tree/master/examples/signon Скорее всего вы опять что-то не то сделали.

Comment: Измененный код: [Code](https://hastebin.com/ameyezunah.js). Тут нет и намека на использование глобальной переменной. Везде юзается `req.user.id`